# Angular 16 and Firebase with Authentification

Tags: angular, typescript, signals, effects

I have implemented authentication using Angular 16 and AngularFire in my application, and it is working fine. However, when I reload the page, my data is lost, and I am unable to retrieve it. I'm having trouble understanding how it works, especially with the new features in Angular 16. Here are my configurations:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
"@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
"@ngrx/data": "^15.4.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^16.0.0",
"@ngrx/entity": "^16.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^16.0.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
"firebase": "^9.8.4",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.13.0"}
```

I will show you the component first. This is where the new feature with signals is already being used:

```
@Component( {
  selector: 'easy-planer-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ],
  imports: [
    JsonPipe,
    NgIf,
    LoginComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    MatButtonModule,
    NgOptimizedImage
  ],
  standalone: true
} )
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  userCredentials: WritableSignal<UserCredential | undefined> = signal( undefined );
  private URL_PROFILE_IMAGE = './assets/defaultProfileImg.jpg';

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  constructor( private readonly authService: AuthService, private sanitizer: 
    DomSanitizer ) {
    effect( () => this.userCredentials = this.authService.userCredentials );
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  public getSantizeUrl( url: string | null | undefined ) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( url ?? 
    this.URL_PROFILE_IMAGE);
  }
}
```

And everything works fine until I reload the page. But first, let's look at the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  userCredentials: WritableSignal<UserCredential | undefined> = signal( undefined );

  constructor( private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router ) {}

  login( email: string, password: string ): void {
    defer( () => this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password ) ).subscribe( userCredentials => {
        this.userCredentials.set( userCredentials );
        this.setTokenToLocalStorage( userCredentials );
      },
      ( error ) => {/*TODO::thoastservice*/},
      () => { /*TODO::thoastservice*/}
    );
  }

  logout() {
    this.angularFireAuth.signOut()
      .then( () => {
        localStorage.clear();
        this.router.navigate( [ '/' ] );
      } )
      .catch( error => { console.log( 'logout: something went wrong', error );} );
  }

  emailSignUp( email: string, password: string ): void {
    defer( () => this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email, password ) ).subscribe( userCredentials => {
        this.userCredentials.set( userCredentials );
        this.setTokenToLocalStorage( userCredentials );
      },
      ( error ) => {/*TODO::thoastservice*/},
      () => { /*TODO::thoastservice*/}
    );
  }

  googleLogin(): void {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly' );
    defer( () => this.oAuthLogin( provider ) ).subscribe( userCredentials => {
        this.userCredentials.set( userCredentials );
        this.setTokenToLocalStorage( userCredentials );
      },
      ( error ) => {/*TODO::thoastservice*/},
      () => { /*TODO::thoastservice*/}
    );
  }

  facebookLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    return defer( () => this.oAuthLogin( provider ) ).pipe(
      tap( userCredentials => this.setTokenToLocalStorage( userCredentials ) )
    );
  }

  private oAuthLogin( provider: AuthProvider ) {
    return this.angularFireAuth.signInWithPopup( provider );
  }

  private setTokenToLocalStorage( userCredentials: UserCredential ) {
    localStorage.clear();
    userCredentials.user?.getIdToken()
      .then( actualToken => {
        localStorage.setItem( 'token', actualToken ?? '' );
        if ( actualToken !== '' && actualToken !== undefined ) {
          this.router.navigate( [ '/home' ] ).then( () => {/**TODO::toastservice*/} );
        }
      } );
  }
}
```

Comment: And now, let's talk about the problem. The signal will naturally be undefined because the page has been reloaded. But how do I retrieve the user credentials using the token, and how do I keep the token up to date? I suspect that an interceptor needs to be used in some way, but I need some help with this.
So, I need a way to, first, keep the token up to date when I reload the page, and, second, retrieve the user credentials to set them in the signal.

Comment: I don't know if this is causing your specific issue, but you have like a dozen race conditions just in the code you've shown. You really should fix that because it will bite you sooner than later.

Comment: Hi thx for ur comment. Im in warup to angular signals and effects... how can i implement this code with observables because if i use observables... statemenagement is not set